# How to safely create an opaque struct and then free it over the FFI boundary?

Tags: rust, ffi

I am using `cbindgen` to generate C bindings for a [small Rust crate](https://github.com/timClicks/ulid-lite) that implements the [ULID specification](https://github.com/ulid/spec). To avoid leaking information, I am generating an opaque struct `ulid_ctx` and returning a pointer to that context object when it is first created. I'm struggling a little bit with reconciling Rust's ownership semantics and C's laissez-faire approach to memory.

```rust
#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
pub struct ulid_ctx {
    seed: u32,
}
```

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ulid_create(seed: u32) -> *mut ulid_ctx {
    let ctx = ulid_ctx { seed: s };
    Box::leak(Box::new(ctx))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn ulid_ctx_destroy(ctx: *mut ulid_ctx) {
    Box::from_raw(ctx);
}
```

Two questions:

1. Does `Box::leak(Box::new(ctx))` correctly allocate a `ctx` value on the heap and then inform Rust that the function no longer owns it?
2. Will `Box::from_raw(ctx);` re-create a Box and then immediately drop it, thereby freeing the memory?

Although it's not a lot of data (32 bits), I would like to avoid creating a memory leak if possible.

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: I would say the assumption is ok. You can make the drop explicit for reading purposes  `drop(Box::from_raw(ctx))`. But it is just my opinion there :)

Comment: That's a good point @Netwave, It's always useful to declare one's intent.

Comment: There's also [`Box::into_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw), so you don't have to (ab)use `Box::leak()`. It does the same thing, but it's designed for that express purpose, and it actually returns a pointer. (`leak()` is designed for a slightly different purpose, which is making the value inside the box eternal and the reference `'static`.)

Answer (score 0):

> Does Box::leak(Box::new(ctx)) correctly allocate a ctx value on the
> heap and then inform Rust that the function no longer owns it?

Indeed, as the name says it leaks the data, so it will not be dropped when going out of scope.
As per *@user4815162342* comment, consider using [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) instead.

> Will Box::from_raw(ctx); re-create a Box and then immediately drop it,
> thereby freeing the memory?

Also true, will build a `Box` then will be dropped. As a note, it may be nice to make the `drop` explicit.

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn ulid_ctx_destroy(ctx: *mut ulid_ctx) {
    drop(unsafe { Box::from_raw(ctx) })
}
```